# Expected argument of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection", "Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity" given

Tags: symfony

I m trying to solve that issue :

> Expected argument of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection", "Proxies__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity" given

I tried many things with no solution. I got it when i try this :

```
$userCollection = $this->createForm(new UserCollectionType(), $userEvalClass);
```

**UserCollectionType**

```
class UserCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('users', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Evaluateurs',
                'empty_value' => '',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => 'EvalFour\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                utilisateurs
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_collection';
    }
}
```

**UserCollection**

```
class UserCollection    
{
    public $users;

    public function __construct($users){
        $this->users = $users;
    }
    public function getUsers(){
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does $userEvalClass look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your buildForm function, set `'multiple' => false,`

When you set it to true, it expects a collection of entities and not just a single entity.

If you do want to have multiple users, then replace `'entity'` with `'collection'`

Comment: yes that's right, but i want to have a multiple select box, that's why i have setted `mutiple = true`. How can i make such select box with collection type ??

Comment: In this case, replace 'entity' with 'choice'. You could also keep the code in your original question and set 'expanded' => true, but that will get messy fast.

Comment: @HugoDozois, the entity is not the right choice, i need a collection, the entity returns one element.

Comment: Out of interest, why is "expanded = true" not a good idea? Where would it get messy?

Comment: I don't remember the exact behavior, but `expanded` simply didn't scale well with many choices. It's strictly a UI/UX issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `replace 'entity' with 'collection'`?! They are seriously different FormTypes, thus not interchangeably replaceable!